# When I hover the image the achor tag doesn't link to the href?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

```
<li ><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://billrandles.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div></li>
<li><a href="#"  id="facebook"><img src="images/facebook.gif" ></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="youtube"><img src="images/youtube.gif" ></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="twitter"><img src="images/twitter.gif"></a></li>
```

Here is my html

```
#sidebar #social ul li a:link{
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    padding-top:0px;
    background:none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#sidebar #social ul li a:visited{
    list-style:none;
}
#sidebar #social ul li div{
    float:left;
    width:80px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Here is my CSS

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your links all have `href="#"`, so they don't link to anywhere except maybe the top of the page...

Comment: The problem was the facebook like button was covering the social img anchors making it where you could not access the "#".

Comment: Does that mean the problem is fixed? If so, you should answer your question and accept your answer.

Comment: I have to wait 18 hours before I can accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook datawidth attribute was overlapping the social link anchor tags.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://billrandles.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true">
```

I changed the data-width to 50px and it fixed the problem.